# Can we invoke a method from a class using IMetaDataImport2 in CLR profiling?

Tags: clr-profiling-api

I'm using CLR profiling API to profile my .NET Core application.

In the method enter hook I can get the classID and metadata.
Is there any way to invoke another function from that class using metadata?

E.g.: Consider the below example. In the class CommonStats When a method enter/exit hook invoked for the function ProcessRequestInternal, I need to invoke a function GetDefaultValue and save the return value.

```
public class CommonStats
    {
        String test = 
        private void ProcessRequestInternal(String str)
        {
           test = str;
        }
        protected override string GetDefaultValue()
        {
            if(test.StartsWith("/")) {
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
            return "FAILURE";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is not recommended (and impossible through the Profiler API) to call managed code from your profiler. The way to do this is performing IL rewriting.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/profiling-overview:

> Although this is possible from a design perspective, the profiling API does not support managed components. A CLR profiler must be
>   completely unmanaged. Attempts to combine managed and unmanaged code
>   in a CLR profiler may cause access violations, program failure, or
>   deadlocks. The managed components of the profiler will fire events
>   back to their unmanaged components, which would subsequently call the
>   managed components again, resulting in circular references.
>
> The only location where a CLR profiler can call managed code safely is
>   in the Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) body of a method. The
>   recommended practice for modifying the MSIL body is to use the JIT
>   recompilation methods in the ICorProfilerCallback4 interface.

A good place to start with IL rewriting is http://www.debugthings.com/2015/09/16/rewriting-il-remotely-part1/.
There is a lot of good information found in David's Broman blog, here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/Documentation/Profiling/davbr-blog-archive